# sybase sql update where record equal to another record

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
| userId | level  |
-------------------
| snoop  | 10     |
| foo    | 0      |
| bar    | 0      |
```

I would like to update the level of all the users to whatever the level of snoop is.

I know that I could get the value and go:
    `update table set level = 10`

but if I didn't want to hardcode the value 10 and needed to do this in one query, how would I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update table
    set level = (select level from table where userId = 'snoop')
```